# Gallery Only Displaying One Thumbnail

Tags: gallery, errors

My image galleries are showing only one thumbnail in the post the gallery sits in. http://themeforward.com/demo2/2013/03/08/image-gallery/

**My single.php markup can be found here:** http://snippi.com/s/akm5jb7

Additionally, previous_image_link and next_image_link are not displaying when the image is clicked (these would lead to the other images in the gallery).

**My entire image.php markup can be found here:** http://snippi.com/s/ajwa5yh

**My gallery shortcode:** `[gallery link="post" ids="2245,2246,2247"]`

Comment: What is the code in setPostViews() function?

Comment: Forgive me if I'm completely missing something but these two source codes don't appear to be the same. Are you linking us to the correct file? I lack the rep points to post images [so here's a link instead](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pOo4j.png).

Comment: That is for a post views counter which does not impact this question.

Comment: Is this with WP3.5? Can you go into the text mode of the post edit screen and paste the gallery shortcode into your question?

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: @AndrettiMilas does your theme have a custom gallery output at all?

Comment: It does not.  Here is my entire functions.php and I'm 90% confident it is not the issue: http://snippi.com/s/z9p0g13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being a problem with a code to pull a custom number of posts via an options panel.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and verify that the attachments come back correctly when queried directly:

```
// helper function to return first regex match
function get_match( $regex, $content ) {
    preg_match($regex, $content, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
} 

// Extract the shortcode arguments from the $post
$shortcode_args = shortcode_parse_atts(get_match('/\[gallery\s(.*)\]/isU', $post->post_content));

// get the attachments specified in the "ids" shortcode argument
$attachments = get_posts(
    array(
        'include' => $shortcode_args["ids"], 
        'post_status' => 'inherit', 
        'post_type' => 'attachment', 
        'post_mime_type' => 'image', 
        'order' => 'menu_order ID', 
        'orderby' => 'post__in', //this forces the order to be based on the order of the "include" param
    )
);

echo 'gallery count:' . count( $attachments );
```

If that count is correct, then the gallery shortcode should be returning correctly. Let me know what that returns.

Comment: Where do I place this?

Comment: drop that in your page template to see if it spits out the correct count of attachments in the gallery which should be 3 given your example of `[gallery link="post" ids="2245,2246,2247"]`

Comment: It returned "gallery count:1"

Comment: Ok, in that case, it sounds like there is truly only one attachment. Can you verify whether or not those other attachment ids actually exist under Media? Or if you have access to the db via phpMyAdmin, you could query the post table directly for those IDs.

One other way to check for their existence is to see if you can get to these URLs:

`/wp-admin/post.php?post=2245&action=edit`
`/wp-admin/post.php?post=2246&action=edit`
`/wp-admin/post.php?post=2247&action=edit`

Comment: Yes, they exist and they are attached to the appropriate post.

Comment: So, it sounds like something else is filtering them out. Can you try the code above on a new page or post and a new gallery and see if that works? Maybe it is something specific to the gallery you have setup or something with your setPostViews function.

Comment: I removed the post views codes (including in functions.php) and created a new gallery.  Same result: http://themeforward.com/demo2/2013/03/18/2253/

Comment: Just tried switching out my functions.php.  It is being filtered.  Now I have to find out why.